# JsonWebToken | get-request validation

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, jwt

I'm currently trying to build a simple login-system based on tokens. I have a simple login-form that sends the credentials to server. Creating a token is also working for me.

If a user is logged in and opens the user-dashboard link manually the server will get a get-request. How can I validate the token then? I cant find a way to access it inside the get-event.

Token-creation:

```
var token = jwt.sign({ Username: 'test' }, app.get('tokenPass'));

// This token is either send as response or via emitting.
```

On client-side I stored it as

```
$window.sessionStorage = token;
```

My problem:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    // req is not including the token
    // I cant deliver the dashboard without
    // validating that the requesting user
    // is logged in.
});
```

I would like to prevent using cookies (that's the point why I picked token-auth). Also I would like being able to access the token from simple emits (which is possible if it gets stored in SessionStorage).

This is a private project so I dont mind getting ideas of alternative ways if needed. I appreciate every help in here.

Thanks very much!

**Edit according to the comments:**

Server-part

```
// Simply tried sending a token for testing purposes
// After a page-refresh I expected being able accessing it
router.get('/', auth, function(req, res) {
    // Sending the index.html
    res.sendFile(exp.get('views') + '/index.html');

    // Token is never delivered
    console.log('BODY: ' + req.body);
    console.log('BODY: ' + req.query);
    console.log('BODY: ' + req.query.token);
    console.log('BODY: ' + req.headers['x-access-token']);

    // New token is send here
    var token = jwt.sign({ username: 'testUser' }, 'SECRET');
    req.io.emit('token', { token: token });
});
```

Client-part

```
<script>
    $(function (){
        var socket = io();

        // Incoming token get sets to sessionStorage
        socket.on('token', function(data) {
            // Is raising and showing token.
            alert('token: ' + data.token);
            $window.sessionStorage.accessToken = data.token;
            $window.sessionStorage = data.token;
        });

        $('#logout').click(function (err){
            sessionStorage.token = null;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Console output of the body is:

```
BODY: undefined
BODY: [object Object]
BODY: undefined
BODY: undefined
```

---

I'm very new to node.js and webcoding itself. So please be patient with me.

Comment: How do you create your tokens? Do you have any npm modules for creating them? (or) you do it in your own way?

Comment: Added a tag for `jwt` as I'm using jsonWebTokens. Adding some code.

Comment: How do you send the request?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Check my edit. Posted the code I currently got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most well known technique for sending json web tokens from client to server, without using session of course, is to send them on request headers.

When you make your ajax call in the client side, add a header like:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Token", jsonWebToken);
  }
  ...
});
```

Then you can verify the json web token in a middleware like:

```
const verifyMiddleware = function(req, res, next){
    const jsonWebToken = req.headers['Access-Token'];
    jwt.verify(jsonWebToken, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
          return res.status(401).send('Bad Auth');
        } else {
          req.user = user;
          next();
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call the middleware from the application like:

```
app.get('/dashboard', verifyMiddleware, function(req, res) {
    // req is not including the token
    // I cant deliver the dashboard without
    // validating that the requesting user
    // is logged in.
});
```

Comment: Where will the user save the token as it needs to be sent in the header?

Comment: browser's local storage is an option. in fact, that's the widest-used method for storing json web tokens. if the api is consumed by something other than a web application, like a native mobile app, you can store the token at shared preferences or sqlite database (or the ios equivalent of those).

Comment: Im new to webcoding, so just for my understanding: If I set the request-header, it will be applied to all future requests? Cant imagine that. What about logging-in , switching to google and then pasting the link to the dashboard into the url-bar of the browser? Shouldnt the browser fire up the request without any modification?

Comment: I'm talking about requests in the context of `open a bookmark from the browser`. How should any scripts be fired there?

Comment: Headers only apply to a single request, not all future requests, so you have to add the header to every request to `/dashboard` endpoint.

If you want to automatically apply the token whenever you open the `/dashboard` from bookmark, you can get the json web token from local storage whenever you fire the ajax request and set the header in ajax code.

Comment: Adding even more into this: you can keep the expiration date in the payload and whenever you load the `/dashboard` page, check the current date and the expiration date. If the token is expired, go back to login page. If the token is still valid, you can use that.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm trying to get. I've edited the question and posted my real current code just to provide something.

Comment: I seriously don't think that res.emit is even a function. If you want to emit a websocket event, use socket.io in the server side and not express, but in your current case, I think that using socket will do much much more harm than good. You can just stick to the regular HTTP request and response.

Comment: Ups that was a wrong version from my code. Edited now. The emit is working this way. I just had to google some stuff to fully understand your answer. I got it. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is a way to send the token to the server and get authentication. Since you are using HTTP, you have a lot of possible ways to do this.
The most common two are cookies and local storage:

### Cookies

Cookies are automatically sent to the server by the browser, and almost all HTTP tools have a way to send them too. So you store the token in a cookie, and on the server side, check the presence of the cookie and validate the JWT within.

#### Pro:

- Use a known technology, so you may have more documentation on how to do that
- Should work with all HTTP tools

### LocalStorage

More detailed by ardilgulez, the logic is that the server have two endpoints. One don't need authentification, and serve a web page that check LocalStorage for the JWT, and use it in a AJAX call to the second server endpoint, which is authenticated and return the data. Once the page have the data, it edit the HTML to print them.
Another advantage to doing this is that you present endpoints which serve only the data, so when one day you want to make another client, be it a "v2" of your website, you don't need to touch the server side.

#### Pro:

- You have a REST like endpoint that get only the relevant data, that any future client may use.
- Depending on how you effectively send the token, it may be easier to configure HTTP tools than with cookies

Also check our discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36251160#36251160)

Comment: Is it safe to store the token in the storage or the cookies where the end user can get access to it?

Comment: @JyotmanSingh Yes, because unless the server is badly configured, it will expire soon anyway. Also, it shouldn't have anything sensible encrypted in it, so there is no problem there either. As always, it is a tool, and a tool is as safe as how you use it. But sure, if someone put SSN or credit card info in a JWT, it is a security breach in itself. Or if the token lives for days...